# How can I horizontally center text in a flexbox box?

Tags: css, flexbox

CSS Code:

```
    .container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  height: 400px;
}
.box1 {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  height: 70%;
  width: 70%;
}
```

I tried vertical-align to center in box1 and nothing happened either. My box with the current code has vertically centered text but not horizontally. Any tips?

Comment: `.box1 {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  height: 70%;
  width: 70%;
}`  is not a flex box and has a specific height without any display reset , let us guess,,  your text stands in it ... display:table-cell and vertical-align can work together for inner content.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest flex containers. This means your box can also have the `display: flex;` property, plus `justify-content: center;` for horizontally centering. Also look into the "place-" property with which you can center things on both axes with one single line of CSS.